# SQL Notifier for 1+ databases

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, notifications

I need to get changes from several tabases into my 1 database, so I guess sql notifier will be best way.
I found interesting application: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach
that works, but only in one database.

Im not asking for full-solution, maybe just some of you work with project like that, and know how can I use sqlnotifier to read data from different databases?

Comment: So i guess the schema of the databases is different ? Or for example same database on different machines...

Comment: Schema is same, only data is different

Comment: Actually my problem is that, I have 3+ computers and 1 main computer, and i want to get data from pc1_database_table, pc2_database_table, pc3_database_table (all db names and table names are the same in all - 4 computers), load it into datatable and insert into main computer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what information you want to track, the SQL Server 2008 developer certification suggests using either CDC (change data capture) or CT (change tracking).

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx) for the details.

You may also consider using the [auditing feature](http://www.bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might want to investigate **Microsoft Sync Framework** to implement what you want, since it looks like you really need a sync solution.

Using this you could sync between two or multiple sql server databases. And since you can define a sync scope, you could restrict it to just the table that you're interested in.

Here are some links where you can read more about this:

[MSDN - How to Choose a Data Synchronization Technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc470041.aspx)

[MSDN - Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync)

[Wikipedia - Microsoft Sync Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework)